# Jedi-vim doesn't work

Tags: python, vim, jedi-vim

I have a issue with VIM. I'm trying to install jedi-vim according to https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim
but when I open vim, it report such error:

```
initialize.py" 25L, 831C'import site' failed; use -v for traceback

Error detected while processing /home/.../.vim/autoload/jedi.vim:

line 285

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/.../.vim/initialize.py", line 10, in <module>

    import os

ImportError: No module named os
```

And when I use Ctrl+Space in vim, it results in

```
Error detected while processing function jedi#completions:                                                               

line    1:

Traceback (most recent call last):

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

In fact, I don't get any error when importing os from the command line..

```
import os

os,

module 'os' from '/usr/local/install/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'
```

Anybody know how to solve this error?Thank You.

Comment: Please use the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that there's something wrong with your VIM. You're probably using vim on mac and there's something wrong with the sys.path.

You should be able to use `:python import os` in VIM. If that doesn't work, Jedi certainly won't.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So I re-compile the vim again and it works!