# trouble loading jedi-vim after install

Tags: python, vim, jedi, jedi-vim

My issue is possibly similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276517/jedi-vim-doesnt-work)

but thought I'd ask jic. I'm on osx and trying to use jedi-vim. I installed jedi using `pip` and then jedi-vim by cloning into the dir that my vim config uses for loading packages. [this one for reference](https://github.com/amix/vimrc). When I start vim with a python program I get the "Please install Jedi if..." message. I cloned vim 74 and configured with +python and +conceal. After still getting the error I looked into the code and found it was an import error.

As an aside, this isn't the best help message. Better might be "Unable to import jedi. Have you installed Jedi?"

I tried import jedi from within vim, as `:python import jedi`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi-0.9.0-     py2.7.egg/jedi/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from jedi.api import Script, Interpreter, NotFoundError, set_debug_function
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi-0.9.0 py2.7.egg/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from jedi.parser import Parser, load_grammar
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi-0.9.0-py2.7.egg/jedi/parser/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from jedi.parser import tree as pt
ImportError: cannot import name tree
```

If this is a build issue, is there a good reference for building vim on mac?

Comment: Two things… 1. SO is not that Jedi's issue tracker. 2. Using someone else's config is pretty much guaranteed to put you into hard to debug problems.

Comment: Can you try importing Jedi from python2.7 directly?

Comment: @DaveHalter it imports from Python without any errors.

Comment: @romainl 1. I'm not logging an issue. I'm trying to get it working. 2. I'm new to vim.

Comment: @crowdedComputeeer Is that the same jedi path and Python version? (2.7) and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi-0.9.0-py2.7.egg/`. Maybe try a homebrew version? The issue above seems very very strange, because tree.py should be in that directory (maybe check that as well).